# How to get the weights of the layer just before the last layer in pretrained inception model

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras

I am new to inception. I am using it for getting 5 prediction for the image.[predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTttZ.jpg). I want to extract the weights for the [layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73lbQ.jpg) which is just before the last one. I was able to get weight for the all layers using code [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIWMe.jpg):

> > for layer in model.layers: print(layer.get_config(), layer.get_weights())

I am expecting which coding can be used to get the weights for the layer just before the last one

Answer (score 0):

You can simply mention the code as below to access the layer just before the last one.

```
layer = model.layers[-2], #can mention layers[-1] to access the last layer
print(layer.get_config())
print(layer.get_weights())
```